# Change the increment of a tkinter spinbox when the button is held down

Tags: tkinter, timing, touchscreen

As the question suggests, I need to change the spinbox increment after a period of time. I need to scroll through the entirety of a 32bit integer using a spinbox (it has to run on a touchscreen. Any other options would also be greatly appreciated). However the user must retain some accuracy when scrolling through, but it also shouldn't take them until the end of time to get from one end of the integer to the other. How to I make it so that the increment of the spinbox changes after the button is held down for x amount of time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Spinbox` takes `repeatdelay` and `repeatInterval` as parameters. If you combine them with a timing mechanism, you can achieve a "quick scroll" effect, like so:

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.s = tk.Spinbox(self)
        self.interval = 0
        self.s["values"] = [i for i in range(32000)]
        self.s.pack()
        self.s.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.on_press)
        self.s.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.on_release)

    def on_press(self,event=None):
        self.interval +=1
        if self.interval <=3: #increases speed if button has been hold for 3 seconds
            self.after(1000,self.on_press)
        else:
            self.s.config(repeatdelay=1, repeatinterval=1)

    def on_release(self,event=None):
        self.interval = 0
        self.s.config(repeatdelay=100, repeatinterval=100)

root = GUI()
root.mainloop()
```